# Как определить последовательность загрузки стилей?

Tags: css, menu, devexpress, jpeg

Использую меню *DevExpress*, в нем картинки.

Во время загрузки страницы явно заметно, как дергаются картинки влево, а потом встают по центру, когда загрузились все *css* и встроенные в элементы стили.

Это точно связано со стилями, т.к. сначала загружается стиль

```
.dxmLite .dxm-item {
    cursor: default;
    text-align: left;
}
```

а потом уже стиль элемента

```
element.style {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
}
```

При этом на странице есть еще контролы *Dev*.

Как настроить последовательность загрузки *css*, 
или как-то блокировать применение стилей, пока не загружены все стили?

Comment: приведите пример кода, инлайн стили подставляются js-ом?

Comment: @Neka вопрос уже решил, уменьшив ширину кнопки, чтобы просто там не было возможности двигаться.
А так, часть стилей устанавливается css, а часть js-ом.